# Php file_get_content with special chars

Tags: php, solr, file-get-contents, htmlspecialchars

Hi i want to delete index from solr so my code

```
file_get_contents("http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update?stream.body=<delete><query>added:[NOW-200DAY TO NOW]</query></delete>&commit=true")
```

but php sends this like

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core/update?stream.body=&amp;lt;delete&amp;gt;&amp;lt;query&amp;gt;added:[NOW-200DAY TO NOW]&amp;lt;/query&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/delete&amp;gt;&amp;amp;commit=true
```

i tried htmlspecialchars($url) but it didn't work.

Comment: Hii... once try with single quotes.. i don't know whether it works, but give a try...

Comment: You're going to have to show some actual code - unless you've written &amp; in your code (you've used an online editor or something like that), PHP would not change entities in a string like that when used directly in `file_get_contents`. Do you have the log entry for the Solr side and a minimum complete example?